Does the CRL validator in PyOpenSSL have a feature to use incremental updates?
I am a beginner, and after reviewing the PyOpenSSL documentation, I could not find an option to enable incremental updates in the CRL validator section. Could you please confirm if the CRL validator in PyOpenSSL supports incremental updates?
I would appreciate it if you could reply regarding whether the CRL validator in PyOpenSSL supports incremental updates.
